# Swift IBoutlet default value

Tags: swift, iboutlet, segmentedcontrol

I have set an IBOutlet function for a segmented control. It will display a value only when a user changes the value, but I am wondering how would I be able to display the default value if the user does not select a different option.

For example, a segmented control with [First, Second, Third] would print Second when the user selects Second, but would not print First until the user selects something else and THEN First.

Very simple answer I'm sure, but I am new to Swift so please excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad` method you should be able to display the default value of the segmented control:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   myLabel?.text = segment.titleForSegmentAtIndex(segment.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for:

```
segmentedControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
```

which returns the title of currently selected segment.

I created a very simple [test project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rnmh1oesccrn6iz/AABuMeRiAmL3nz-vdH2uCP0ya?dl=0) demonstrating how that works.

Comment: Putting it in the view did load did the trick! Thanks for showing me an example!